# js save data on page unload does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, database, save, onbeforeunload, onunload

Im trying to save some data on page unload, this is my current script

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
    if(snippetChanged){
        //save it
        snippetChanged = false
        var changeData = {
            code: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(snippetEditor.getValue(), 'key').toString(),
            name: path[0]
        }
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlHttp.open('POST', '/userhome/updateSnippet', true);
        xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(changeData)); 
    }
})
```

however this only works partially (resetting the webpage in firefox), I have no clue why this is happening, any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and name it *saveData()*

```
function saveData(){
   // your code to save the data
}
```

at the Body html tag put the onunload="saveData()"
example:

```
<body onunload="saveData()">
```

Comment: ok, so I know I marked your answer as correct, but I just noticed that it does not work in google chrome (from what Ive found it doesnt work same as the other browsers) is there a fix or a way around this?